# Issue with cells flicker when loading UICollectionViewCell Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am currently having an issue with UICollectionViewCell and when it gets loaded.

Here is the link to the [video](https://youtu.be/6_uIsGKXy5s) to see it in action

Below is my code in viewDidLoad i call

```
retrieveUrls { (success) in
    if success {
        self.filterImageLabel(handler: { (success) in
            if success {
                if self.spinner != nil {
                    self.spinner.stopAnimating()
                    self.spinner.isHidden = true
                }
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

In retrieveUrls i am parsing the Url to retrieve image URL and for filterImageLabel i set up an photoUrlArray to use with collectionView indexpath

```
func filterImageLabel(handler: @escaping (_ status: Bool) -> ()) {
    photoUrlArray = photoUrlArray.filter {$0.label == "Large Square"}
    if photoUrlArray.count > 0 {
        handler(true)
    }
}
```

Methods for CollectionView

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return photoUrlArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photoCell", for: indexPath) as? PhotoCell {
        cell.updateCellImage(imageUrl: self.photoUrlArray[indexPath.row].source)
        return cell
    }

    return PhotoCell()
}
```

And Finally in photocell class i am setting up the image

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    photoImg.image = nil
}

func updateCellImage(imageUrl : String) {

    Alamofire.request(imageUrl).responseImage(completionHandler: { (response) in

        guard let image = response.result.value else {return}
        self.photoImg.image = image

    })

}
```

I have looked at various different thread on stack-overflow. however cannot seem to resolve the issue.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method for CollectionView is as follows:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

  if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photoCell", for: indexPath) as? PhotoCell {

    // ********* ISSUE IS HERE *********
    let imageurl = URL(string: self.photoUrlArray[indexPath.row].source)
    cell.photoImg.af_setImage(withURL: imageurl!)
    return cell
  }

  return PhotoCell()

}
```

Comment: Thank you @vipulp444, this answer works as a charm. No more flickering on screen